# ¿Cuál es mi error en este programa basado en la clase String? Creo que las variables están mal pero no se porque

Tags: java

Mi programa trata de obtener la primera la segunda y la última letra de un nombre, y luego concatenarlas:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Ejercicioo9 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ultimaLetra;
        String nombre,nombre12,nombren;
        int letra1;
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Ingrese su nombre: ");
        nombre=entrada.next();
        ultimaLetra = nombre.length()-1;
        nombre12=nombre.substring(0,2);
        nombre.charAt(ultimaLetra)   //aca me sale un error.
        System.out.print("la union de las letras en las posiciones (0),(1)y(n-1) es: " + nombre12 + nombre.charAt(ultimaLetra));
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio. También a leer [ask]. A tu pregunta le hace falta, cuándo menos, indicar cuál es el mensaje exacto de error que estás obteniendo, y si es al compilar o al ejecutar. De entrada, noto que te falta un `;` en esa línea. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bienvenido a Stackoverflow.

El error aquí:

```
nombre.charAt(ultimaLetra)  //aca me sale un error.
```

es porque debes terminar la línea con `;`.

Poniéndolo así desaparecerá el error:

```
nombre.charAt(ultimaLetra); //aca YA NO me sale un error. PERO ¿qué sentido tiene esta línea?
```

Aunque esa línea está de más, porque ya obtienes el dato aquí:

```
System.out.print("la union de las letras en las posiciones (0),(1)y(n-1) es: " + nombre12 + nombre.charAt(ultimaLetra));
```

Esa línea tendría sentido sólo si quisieras hacer una asignación.

Otra recomendación, evita usar nombres de variables como: `nombre12` ... cuando haya que analizar ese código no hay quien le meta el diente. Usa nombres como `firstChar, secondChar, lastChar`... (sólo con verlas sabrás que representan el primer el segundo o el último carácter) no importa que uses el inglés, es muy práctico para programar y universalizas el código. Pero al ver algo como `nombre12` dentro de 6 meses tú mismo que declaraste la variable te preguntarás *¿qué significa `nombre12`?* Y no hay nada más terrible que sentirse perdido en su propio código.

Comment: Muchas gracias, fueron mis primeras preguntas, y si, es importante buenos nombres a las variables. Saludos y gracias por corregir esta pregunta